# Send file to Jenkins from web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ftp, jenkins-plugins

I have a web server is running in Ubuntu (AWS EC2) and I would like to send a file on it. To do that I would like to use Jenkins but I didn't find a plugin or a good configuration to do it.

The problem when I configure a plugin or something else in Jenkins they ask a password, so my password to the server is encrypted by ssh and they cannot read it.

I tried with :

- FTP repository hosts
- Publish over FTP
- Publish over SSH

Is there someone can help me please ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you have to send a file to the Webserver from Jenkins?

Comment: Did you check this? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin

Comment: Yes the build said :
SSH: Connecting from host [workgroup]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [Preprod] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [Preprod] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not create or change to directory. Directory [var]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE

It seems I get an error with the repository, I tried in the local repository and the server, both of them, fail

Comment: Ok where is your Jenkins on local or on the instance?

Comment: I try with Jenkins in local and on the instance. In the local when I test the connection it works but when I launch the build there is an error.
With the Jenkins on the instance I get this :
Failed to connect or change directory

jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect session for config [Preprod]. Message [java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]

I allow the IP adress in the security group

Comment: I solved the connection timed out but I got this :

ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Permission denied]
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE

So I can connect but it doesn't want publish my file even if the connection is good. I think my user don't have the permission to publish. I'm going to look for in this way

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In fact it was a problem with the access. I used this command : sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu [Directory] where I have my files. Then when I launched the build it was succeed.

Hope this help.

Thank you